# How do I move an existing wallet into Parity?

Tags: wallets, parity, ether.li

My Ethereum wallet is malfunctioning and I want to move the Ethers into Parity. Not sure how though. I have the backup keys etc. of my existing wallet (Etherli).

Can anyone help?